# Why am I getting "vector iterators incompatible"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, vector, iterator

Why does this code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.reserve(v.size() * 2);  // Reserve enough space to keep iterators valid
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
    return 0;
}
```

give me the debug assertion failure, *Expression: vector iterators incompatible* (Visual C++ 2008)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Iterators corresponding to elements are only invalidated when the vector has to be reallocated, which `reserve` avoids.

However, `v.end()` won't stay valid.

The Standard's description of `push_back` and `insert` guarantees that

> Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens,
>   all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

`v.end()` is not "before the insertion point".

Comment: +1 Dang... that's so darn annoying. What's the best workaround?

Comment: A `for` loop operating on the index?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I don't imagine `insert` avoids this mess?

Comment: @chris: No, it's described in the same language, iterators at or after the insertion point become invalid.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry, I meant a workaround using iterators... this was just an example to show the problem; `for` loops with indices don't generalize well to other containers. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: Modifying a container mid-iteration doesn't generalize well.  I suppose you could copy all except the last element, and then `push_back` it separately following the loop.

Comment: Aw man that's ugly. :( (Iterating a container while modifying it is perfectly fine in principle though, as long as the caller can reserve enough space before having you insert into it.) Oh well...

Comment: @Mehrdad: How about using `std::copy_n` and `v.size()`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Doesn't exist in C++03 :( And it's quite limited too, since it wouldn't work for e.g. `copy_if`.

Comment: @Mehrdad, You *could* roll your own I suppose. For `copy_n`, you could use [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n). It's easy to adjust for working with a predicate, but really only so for others if you don't need to recreate too much :/ It feels bad doing that sort of thing.

Comment: @chris: Well, `copy_n` is the easiest case to do that for, but the real problem is with `copy_if` and more complicated cases, where you don't know how many elements you will insert exactly. But even for `copy_n`, rolling your own implementation isn't a great idea: `std::copy` is often optimized by the implementation (e.g. with `memcpy`) for POD types and such, and you won't be able to do that correctly and efficiently with `copy_n`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The memcpy optimization for blit-able objects should be even easier with `copy_n` than `copy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Uhm, not really. Blittability of objects isn't enough -- I need to know the containers' iterator implementations as well, to be able to convert them to pointers. It's easy enough for `vector`, but not for e.g. `deque`. And writing a `copy_n` function that only works on `vector`s of PODs is rather silly and pointless.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I didn't say it was easy.  I said it's easier than with `std::copy`, which also requires contiguity before turning to `memcpy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your assumption is still wrong though. `std::copy` doesn't require contiguity of all the elements; for example, consider `deque`, where only some of the elements might be contiguous. `std::copy` could very well contain optimizations for calling `memcpy`'s for each contiguous region, but there's no way I could implement that myself.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The contiguity requirement is the same for `copy` and `copy_n`.  Someone managed to implement it, so it clearly is possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Neither `copy` nor `copy_n` requires contiguity, so I'm not sure what requirement you're referring to. "Someone" managed to do it because he was designing both the containers and the algorithms, so he didn't have an abstraction barrier to break. My point is that it's impossible to do this **portably** because there's no way for me to optimize it without knowing the internals of each container whose iterator might be given to me, but the implementation certainly can (and does, in some cases).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Optimization of `std::copy` requires (1) using a trait to detect random-access iterators or (2) special-casing for containers which have contiguous sequences.  It's the optimization of using `memcpy` to implement `std::copy` that requires contiguity, and this is the same for `copy_n`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: We're not going anywhere without an example. Can you demonstrate to me an example of how you think an optimized `copy_n` could be implemented for `std::deque<T>::iterator`?

Comment: Neither `std::copy` nor `copy_n` can portably be optimized for a container without random-access iterators.  Please note that the author of the Standard library is prohibited from using non-portable optimizations, because `std::copy` has to work for specializations of `std::deque` also.  `copy_n` doesn't face any problems not encountered with `copy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *"Neither `std::copy` nor `copy_n` can portably be optimized for a container without random-access iterators."*... You completely ignored the question, so I'll ask it again: **Can you show me a portable optimized example of `std::copy[_n]`** for `std::deque::iterator`, which **does** have random-access iterators? (Specializations are 100% irrelevant -- the implementation could easily detect a user-defined specialization and use slower code for it, e.g. by failing to find a special type inside that code. There's no need to compromise correctness here.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27728/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-mehrdad)

Comment: So if you v.reserve() without allocating, `v.end()` is not usable until it allocates?