# Why does this iterator comparison fail?

Tags: c++

Please see the following code:

```
if((pos = find()) != _sym.end())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

`pos` is a scoped variable of type `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` where `T` is a POD-struct containing a pair of the same type of iterator.

`_sym` is a private class member variable of type `std::vector<T>`.

The example code throws a runtime assertion error with the message `Expression: vector iterators incompatible` under Visual Studio 2013. The error occurs in `<vector>` at line 240.

On the other hand, if I re-write the code:

```
pos = find();
if(pos != _sym.end()) // do stuff
```

then, disco.

I'm fairly sure that comparing an initialized iterator (such as `end()`) with an uninitialized iterator causes this assertion; What I don't understand is if/how `pos` is not considered in an initialized state when the comparison operator is executed.

Comment: The code you showed is irrelevant. Please prepare a code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Have you tried other compiler? Providing SSCCE would be nice. It might be a VS bug/thingy. I'd say VS is known to have troubles occasionally with similar stuff. I think I saw two occasions it refused to compile proper code which was a bit convoluted.

Comment: If might be an order of operations. In the first one, `_sym.end()` can be called before `find()`, where as in the second one, `find()` will always be called first.

Comment: What does find look like? If I try your code with std::find in VS2013 I don't get any errors.

Comment: This might be relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855634/why-am-i-getting-vector-iterators-incompatible

I don't suppose find() changes _sym.end()?

Comment: @QuestionC: Good call, an edge case is calling another function which push_backs my container. Should have been a `const` function which would have illuminated the issue. Make an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be relevant.

[Why am I getting "vector iterators incompatible"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855634/why-am-i-getting-vector-iterators-incompatible)

I don't suppose find() changes _sym.end()?